Why am I seeing two lines within each subplot?
I am currently working on graphing a set of signals' Fourier Transforms. The issue that I am currently facing is that there seems to be a flat line in every single subplot, whose origins I am unsure of. Each set of data only has one set of y values, therefore there should only be one line in each subplot.
This is the plot I am getting currently. Note the flat line near the bottom of each subplot:

Here is the code for the graph generation. The parsedData variable is a 2D array of the given data. parsedData[0] gives the time step values, while all following indices are arrays of y values.
Code:
def GenerateFFT(parsedData,T):
    colors = ["red","green","blue","purple","orange","cyan","pink","black"]
    parsedDataY=parsedData[1:]


    print(parsedDataY[len(parsedDataY)-1])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(parsedDataY),sharex=True,sharey=True)
    #FourierValues = [[] for _ in range(4)]
    for i in range(len(parsedDataY)):



        signal = np.array(parsedDataY[i],dtype=float)
        N=signal.size   
        print(f"Signal Size at i={i}: {N}")
        
        x=np.arange(30.0,49.035,.005)
        
        fourier =  np.fft.fft(signal)  
        fourierFreq = np.fft.fftfreq(n=signal.size,d=1.0/T)

        #FourierValues[i].append(fourier)

        print(np.sqrt(np.sqrt(fourier.real**2+fourier.imag**2)).tolist)
        ax[i].plot(fourierFreq,np.sqrt(fourier.real**2+fourier.imag**2),color=colors[i],linewidth=.75)
        ax[i].set_yscale("log")
        ax[i].set_xbound(lower=-10,upper=10)
    plt.setp(ax, xlim=(0,10),ylim=ax[0].get_ylim())
    fig.suptitle("Fourier Transforms of Monochromatic Wavetrains with Amplitude Modulation",fontweight="bold")
    fig.supxlabel("Frequency (Hz)",fontweight="bold")
    fig.supylabel("Amplitude (cm) on Logarithmic Scale",fontweight="bold")
    

    
    plt.show()


np.abs(fourier) is easy for calculate magnitude

Matplotlib will connect adjacent points in your data structure. Verify that you don't have any data points that are very far apart in frequency space but adjacent in your array. You seem to be plotting fourierFreq, so print out np.abs(np.diff(fourierFreq)).max(). That will tell you the largest frequency distance between adjacent points in your plot; does the result seem reasonable to you?

This question is similar to: Got an extra line on python plot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is warping freq axis.
Use np.fft.fftshift
fourier=np.fft.fftshift(fourier)
fourierFreq=np.fft.fftshift(fourierFreq)


I think you meant fourierFreq=np.fft.fftshift(fourierFreq) (with the extra .fft in the middle), but otherwise I agree with you. The original routine returns something like [0,df,..., fmax, -fmax, .... -df]
